# Graph API in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am totally confused with using the Facebook graph API. E.G. if I do this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed, I get:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "from": {
        "name": "Souvik Basu",
        "id": "123456"
      },
      "story": "Souvik Basu shared \"jus'sayin\"'s photo.",
      "story_tags": {
        "19": [
          {
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "\"jus'sayin\"",
            "offset": 19,
            "length": 11,
            "type": "page"
          }
        ],
        "0": [
          {
            "id": 123456,
            "name": "Souvik Basu",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 11,
            "type": "user"
          }
        ]
```

But, how do I get a particular story in my android code? Also why are there 19th and 0th sory tags?
I have the standard Facebook-Android code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand where exactly is your problem...

Are you using the [facebook android sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/)? If so, then it's very simple to get an graph object to your "android code", for example:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(...);

String response = facebook.request("/me/feed");
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

This example shows the normal [API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) but you can also use [Async API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/).

As for the keys of the story_tags, this is what it says in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/):

> object containing fields whose names are the indexes to where objects
>   are mentioned in the message field; each field in turn is an array
>   containing an object with id, name, offset, and length fields, where
>   length is the length, within the message field, of the object
>   mentioned